# Enable/Disable button through java script in JSF

Tags: java, javascript, jsf, jsf-2, primefaces

I am working on a jsf project where i have to integrate a applet for figure print verification for user. My applet is working fine and i am getting a boolean value from my applet to jsf page. At first my commandbutton in jsf form will be disable. I just want to enable my jsf button when ever my applet return true value. I am pasting my code here.

My jsf code is:

```
<!DOCTYPE composition PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<!-- <ui:composition xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
    xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
    xmlns:c="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core"
    template="/layouts/BasicTemplate.xhtml"
    xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html">
    <ui:define name="content">
        <div> -->

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
    xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
    xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
    xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
    xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui">

<ui:composition template="/layouts/BasicTemplate.xhtml">
    <ui:define name="content">
        <div class="container">

        <script>

        function doAlert(s)
        {
            if(s=="true")
                {
                alert(s);
                rc();
                alert('hi i am');
                }
            else
                {
                 alert("Wrong Finger Print");
                }
        }

        </script>


          <h:form class="form-horizontal" id="myform" >
                <div class="row">
                    <!-- <p:growl id="msgs" sticky="true" showDetail="true" /> -->
            <!-- <div>
                <div>&nbsp;</div>
                <div>
                    <c:if test="${not empty param.login_error}">
                        <div>
                            Your login attempt was not successful, try again.
                            <br/>
                            Reason: #{sessionScope.SPRING_SECURITY_LAST_EXCEPTION.message}
                            <br/>
                        </div>
                    </c:if>
                    <form name="f" action="${request.contextPath}/j_spring_security_check" method="post">
                        <fieldset>
                            <h4>User Login</h4> 
                            <div>
                                <div>
                                    <span>Username:</span>
                                    <c:if test="${not empty param.login_error}">
                                        <c:set var="username" value="${sessionScope.SPRING_SECURITY_LAST_USERNAME}" />
                                    </c:if>
                                    <input type="text" name="j_username" value="#{username}" />
                                    <br/>
                                    <span class="password">Password:</span>

                                    <input type="password" name="j_password" />

                                </div>
                                <div>
                                    <div>
                                        <input name="submit" type="submit" value="Login" />
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </fieldset>
                    </form>
                </div> 
            </div> -->


        <h:messages />
        <h:panelGrid columns="3" cellpadding="4" border="0" columnClasses="control-label">

            <h:outputText  value="Username :" />
            <h:inputText id="username" value="#{loginBean.login}" label="username" style="width: 200;" /> 
            <p:watermark for="username" value="Username" ></p:watermark>

            <h:outputLabel for="password" value="Password :" />
            <h:inputSecret id="password" value="#{loginBean.password}" label="password" style="width: 200;"/> 
            <p:watermark for="password" value="Password"></p:watermark>

            <p:spacer></p:spacer>
            <!-- <p:commandButton value="Login" action="#{loginBean.logMeIn}" widgetVar="mybutton" /> -->

            <p:commandButton id="loginButton" value="Login" action="#{loginBean.logMeIn}" widgetVar="mybutton"  disabled="#{!loginBean.enabled}"/>
            <p:remoteCommand name="rc" update="loginButton" actionListener="#{loginBean.enableButton}" /> 
            <p:spacer></p:spacer>
            <h:outputText value="#{loginBean.enabled}"></h:outputText>
            <applet id="fingureprintapplet" name="fingureprint" codebase="classes"  code="fingerprintntscanner.MyClassApplet.class" archive="#{facesContext.externalContext.requestContextPath}/FIngerprintntScanner.jar,#{facesContext.externalContext.requestContextPath}/lib/NBioBSPJNI.jar" width="300" height="400">

            </applet>
        </h:panelGrid>

        </div>
        </h:form>

        </div>
    </ui:define>
</ui:composition>



</html>
```

and the script to enable the button is

JS Is

```
    function doAlert(s)
    {
        if(s)
            {
            alert(s);
            rc();
            }
    }

    </script>
```

Bean Is :

```
import java.io.Serializable;
import javax.faces.application.FacesMessage;
import javax.faces.bean.ManagedBean;
import javax.faces.bean.ManagedProperty;
import javax.faces.bean.SessionScoped;
import javax.faces.context.FacesContext;


@ManagedBean(name = "loginBean")
@SessionScoped
public class LoginBean implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    private String login;
    private String password;
    private boolean enabled;


    public String getLogin() {
        return login;
    }

    public void setLogin(String login) {
        this.login = login;
    }

    public String getPassword() {
        return password;
    }

    public void setPassword(String password) {
        this.password = password;
    }




    public void enableButton() {
        System.out.println("chandan");
        enabled = true;
    }

    public boolean isEnabled() {
        System.out.println("hi");
        return enabled;
    }

    public void setEnabled(boolean enabled) {
        this.enabled = enabled;
    }


}
```

But nothing is working. alert giving me true and false value. Please help

Comment: where are you disabling it?

Comment: i have written in primeface itself disble=true

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to enable the button by JSF, not by JavaScript/HTML DOM. If you need to do it through JS you can use remoteCommand. Something like this should work:

XHTML:

```
<p:commandButton id="loginButton" value="Login" action="#{loginBean.logMeIn}" widgetVar="mybutton"  disabled="#{!bean.enabled}"/>

<p:remoteCommand name="rc" update="loginButton" actionListener="#{bean.enableButton}" />
```

JS:

```
function doAlert(s)
        {
            if(s)
                {
                alert(s);
                rc();
                }
        }
```

Bean:

```
private boolean enabled;

public void enableButton() {
    enabled = true;
}

public boolean isEnabled() {
    return enabled;
}
```

Comment: I have done as you have told but nothing working. still button is not enabling.

Comment: Is the enableButton() method beeing invoked? Are there any JS errors in the browser?

Comment: No the method is not envoking. I think rc(); is not working

Comment: Could you make an edit to your post and post the new code you are using? The button, the remoteCommand and your bean?

Comment: I have update the question please check it

Comment: The example by @Kaminsky is a direction.  If there is no passing of the s variable to the remote command and there is no setting enabled to false anywhere, the button will never be disabled.

Comment: @ Kukeltje please help me to solve it

Comment: @ASADUL have you checked your browser for any JS errors?

Comment: @ Emil Kaminski i am getting the alert message .

Answer (score 2):

Have a Look at the  documentation here: 
http://www.primefaces.org/docs/guide/primefaces_user_guide_5_0.pdf

Primefaces Command Button supports enable/disable using the widgetVar.

so, with your button

```
<p:commandButton id="loginButton" value="Login" 
action="#{loginBean.logMeIn}" widgetVar="mybutton"  
disabled="#{!loginBean.enabled}"/>
```

you could use

```
function doAlert(s)
{
    if(s)
        {
        alert(s);
        myButton.disable(); // or enable()
        }
}
```

and it should work as expected. Basically no need for `remote command` here - but it should work as well.

Comment: Although it might not be relevant, as PF 5.0, you should consider using widgetVar with PF namespace: so "mybutton.enable()" becomes "PF('mybutton').enable()". Also disabling buttons on client side only, may cause security issues. But still a good answer

Comment: @EmilKaminski Good point on the PF-namespace and security issues.

Comment: @dognose i have tried your code but still error is there

Comment: function doAlert(s){
            if(s=="true"){
                alert(s);
                PF('mybutton').enable()
                alert('hi i am');
                }
            else{
              alert("Wrong FingerPrint");
             } i have tried it but still error -  @dognose

Comment: @dognose  the button has been enable now but now mu form is not submiting. what is the problem.

Comment: @ASADUL - I am having same issue of form not getting submitted after enabling command button using widgetVar. Did you find any fix for this ?